# React Typescript types for monaco-editor

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, typescript-typings, monaco-editor

Having the following code snippet that works fine with React + Javascript:

```
import React, { useRef } from "react";

import Editor from "@monaco-editor/react";

function App() {
  const editorRef = useRef(null);

  function handleEditorDidMount(editor, monaco) {
    editorRef.current = editor;
  }

  function showValue() {
    alert(editorRef.current?.getValue());
  }

  return (
    <>
      <button onClick={showValue}>Show value</button>
      <Editor
        height="90vh"
        defaultLanguage="javascript"
        defaultValue="// some comment"
        onMount={handleEditorDidMount}
      />
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

[Sandbox here](https://codesandbox.io/s/get-value-r9be5?file=/src/App.js:0-563).

I need to use it in a React + Typescript app so I have to add types.

What type should be used for `editor`?

Tried like this:

```
  function handleEditorDidMount(editor: HTMLInputElement) {
    editorRef?.current = editor;
  }

  function showValue() {
    // eslint-disable-next-line no-alert
    alert(editorRef?.current?.getValue());
  }
```

For the first method, the error is:

```
The left-hand side of an assignment expression may not be an optional property access.ts(2779)
const editorRef: React.MutableRefObject<null>
```

For the second:

```
Property 'getValue' does not exist on type 'never'.ts(2339)
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 6):

- import type `onMount`

  ```
  import MonacoEditor, { OnMount } from "@monaco-editor/react";
  ```

if you hover on `onMount`:

```
  type OnMount = (editor: monaco.editor.IStandaloneCodeEditor, monaco: Monaco) => void
```

- use it on handleDidMount:

  const handleEditorDidMount:OnMount=(editor) {
  editorRef?.current = editor;
  }

if you see the type,`handleEditorDidMount` takes 2 args

```
const handleEditorDidMount:OnMount=(editor,_monaco) {
    editorRef?.current = editor;
  }
```

Since you are using `OnMount` type, args type will be inferred by typescript:

```
          editor: editor.IStandaloneCodeEditor
```

Answer (score 0):

The returned type of `useRef(null)` is `React.MutableRefObject<null>`. But you want typescript to know you're gonna pass an input element to the ref, so you have to explicitily set its type `const editorRef = useRef(null) as React.MutableRefObject<null | HTMLInputElement>;`

`editorRef.current` will always be defined, but the type of `editorRef.current` is now `null | HTMLInputElement`, because the type of current is the type you pass into the generic of `React.MutableRefObject`.

Regarding this error.

```js
The left-hand side of an assignment expression may not be an optional property access.ts(2779)
const editorRef: React.MutableRefObject<null>
```

`editorRef.current` will always be defined. The value however can be `null` as you have explicitily typed. So no need for the `?`

Knowing this you can adjust your last part of code to

```js
function showValue() {
    // eslint-disable-next-line no-alert
    alert(editorRef.current?.getValue());
}
```